# Problema al guardar imagen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo este código html:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-foto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Actualizar Foto de Perfil</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-5">
           <span class="archivo">
            <input type="file" id="archivo" name="archivo">
           </span>
           <label for="archivo">
            <span>Selecciona una foto</span>
           </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <div id="foto">
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Rotar" onClick="rotar();">
        </form>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" style="display: none;" id="error-foto">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 Error al actualizar foto.
        </div>
        <div class="cargar-foto" style="display: none;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="subirArchivo();">Actualizar Foto</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y tengo este código javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //función que observa los cambios del campo file y obtiene información
    $(':file').change(function()
    {
        filePreview(this);
    });
});

function filePreview(input) 
{
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#foto').html('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="200" height="200" id="img-foto"/>');
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

function subirArchivo()
{
    var archivo = $("#archivo")[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("archivo", archivo.files[0]);

    //hacemos la petición ajax  
    $.ajax({
      url: '../includes/upload_foto.php',  
      type: 'POST',
      //Form data
      data: formData,
      //necesario para subir archivos via ajax
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function(){
          $(".cargar-foto").show();
          $(".cargar-foto").html("<img src='../img/ajax-loader.gif'>");       
      },
      //una vez finalizado correctamente
      success: function(data){
        var datos = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  

        if(datos.estado == 1)      
            updateFoto(datos.archivo);
        else
        {
            $("#cargar-foto").hide();
            $("#error-foto").show();
        }
      }
    });
}

function updateFoto(foto)
{     
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../includes/acciones/persona/updateFoto.php",
    data: "id_persona=" + id_persona + "&foto=" + foto, 
    success: function(data)
    { 
        if(data == 1)
          window.location.href = "perfil.php?var=" + window.btoa(id_persona);
        else
        {
          $("#cargar-foto").hide();
          $("#error-foto").show();
        }
    }
  });
}

function rotar()
{
  angulo += 45;
  $("#foto").rotate(({angle:angulo}));
}
```

El problema es el siguiente, cuando cargo la imagen en la vista previa se visualiza rotada, como pueden ver pongo código que rota elementos html,
cuando subo la imagen una vez que ya la coloque bien a través de la rotación se sube bien, pero cuando la muestro en la página se visualiza tal y como se visualizó en el momento de cargarla osea se muestra rotada.

Como puedo solucionar esto??

Comment: puedes ver esto `Vadim Boltach`  [rotate_image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251338/jquery-image-preview-exif-rotation-issue#answer-28843763)

Comment: No funciona nada de lo que viene en ese enlace

Comment: as intentando con una imagen normal! en su posicion correcta? y te sige pasando o son las el celular?

Comment: Con las imágenes que tengo problemas son con las del celular

Comment: En este caso debes verificar el `width` y el `height` de la imagen, a mayor `height` forma normal celular en vertical en cambio si mayor `width` forma horizontal y aplicas al rotacion de acuerdo a esto le pasas orientacion w o h y ya sabes para donde girarla y cuanto y antes de guardarla le dices a php que haga la rotacion pertinente